# Alternative build system for .NET utilities

Tags: c#, .net, build, components, libraries

Currently I'm using multiple .NET projects for each utility library in each domain. Say I need access to Win API for Mouse/Keyboard/Joystick control, or utilities to work with Files and Folders, I have distinct libraries for each, so lets call these "Core.HumanInterface" and "Core.Files". With this system, a lot of unnecessary code gets pulled into any app, inflating build sizes and slowing download times.

In Flash/ActionScript you could add a build-path into your project, and the code in those directories would get automatically pulled in *as they are used*. Only used classes would get built into your binary, and would be compiled into the EXE itself, without needing individual DLLs per library. And you didn't need to add "references" to dozens of different "projects".

Does .NET have any alternate build system such as the build-paths mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

This is what a linker does.  .NET actually has one, `al.exe`, but creating the .netmodule files is not directly supported by the build system.  Setting up your own makefile based build system to leverage the C# compiler's `/target:module` option is something you are going to regret deeply some day.

Stick with Flash is download size is your paramount concern, it was optimized heavily for that.  Having assemblies with a lot of unused code is otherwise not a concern at runtime, .NET only ever loads code that is actually used.

Comment: Hmm, clunky isn't quite descriptive enough, it is a source control nightmare.

Comment: Using a similar system, is it possible to "Add a link" to a whole directory and all the files in it or something?